# What's the endpoint of Fabric.io Android Plugin for login and uploading APK?

Tags: android-studio, google-fabric, fabric.io

I'm trying to figure out what's the endpoint of Fabric.io Android Plugin for login and uploading APK?

I'll use this information to whitelist the domain, so we can use the plugin when we are connected to the company's network.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the Android Studio log file and it's https://api.crashlytics.com

Answer (score 0):

To support a blocked traffic device, just whitelist the following domains on ports 80 and 443: *.fabric.io *.crashlytics.com

It's important to note that we don't support IP whitelisting because we use AWS and our IPs changevery often. If you're using domains as a way of obtaining IP addresses, please be aware that the IP addresses will change very frequently - potentially every 24 hours.